# Allowed memory size exhausted - Imagecreatetruecolour();

Tags: php

I am having a very frustrating problem when trying to use this function to create thumbnails from Jpg or Png files.

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't work I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in * on line 34
```

From reading up online I think I must have a memory leak but I'm not sure what is causing it.

Here is the function:

```
    function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

    $fileType = pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    echo $fileType;

    if ($fileType == 'JPG' || $fileType == 'JPEG' || $fileType == 'jpg' || $fileType == 'jpeg') {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    } else if ($fileType == 'PNG' || $fileType == 'png') {
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);

    return true;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [imagedestroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php)

Comment: Thanks for that! Would I put that straight after the imagecreatetruecolor line or at the end of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code into the top of the code:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
```